# Generalization of Minkowski's theorem

Tags: computational-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I would like to prove a generalized version of the Minkowski's theorem, but I don't quite know how to do it.

Here is what I would like to prove: Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is convex, symmetric around the origin, bounded, and such that ${\rm volume}(X) > k2^d$, then $X$ contains at least $2k$ lattice points.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, in your case $d = 2$ and, as you say, ${\rm vol}(X) = 12$. But for $k = 3$ it is not true that ${\rm vol}(X) > 3 \cdot 2^d = 12$. So I don't think that the condition for the the volume of the set $X$ is satisfied in your case.

Comment: Why? In you set, I have the points $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1), (1,1), (-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1)$.